# Examples of (commercial) websites using shiny-apps

Tags: r, shiny

Can anyone name examples of (commercial) websites that offer webservices based on shinyapps? I am not talking about showcases like [showmeshiny.com](http://showmeshiny.com) or [shiny.rstudio.com/gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery), but websites that make their money with shiny-powered apps.